# 3D Visualization with color weights in R

Tags: r, model, 3d, visualization

Can you recommend me a method to visualize a data set in R like in a kind of the  lattice package (point clouds visualization) but with changing colors in those segments where the concetration of the points  is higher?
E.g. if there is a point with no neighboures on distance 10 at coordinates equal to 0:-1:6 then this point will be coloured blue. And when there is a point with many very near neighbours with coordianates 100:100:100 (and the neighbours are like 99:100:100), then this point would be red.

Also it is necessary to be able to produce such a visualization in 3D.

Is there such a sollution?

Example:

```
x = (sample.int(101,size=100,replace=TRUE)-1)/100
y = (sample.int(101,size=100,replace=TRUE)-1)/100
z = (sample.int(101,size=100,replace=TRUE)-1)/100
data = data.frame(x,y,z)
```

Then I want to develop something in plot.ly, for example this

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(type = 'scatter3d', x = x, y = y, z = z, mode = "markers")
```

This provides a nice result but I want more visualization especially in colour. Is there a sollution?

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways you can do this. You could define your own method based on distance from a defined center, or use clustering methods.

For instance, using kmeans clustering:

```
set.seed(20)
dataCluster <- kmeans(data, 5, nstart = 20)$cluster %>% 
  as.factor()

plot_ly(type = 'scatter3d', x = x, y = y, z = z, mode = "markers", color = dataCluster)
```